# roxygenize: Cannot open the connection

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm having trouble roxygenizing a package.  It was last working several months ago and I haven't checked since, so not sure if a snippet of code I added broke it, if my system's configuration changed, or if roxygen2 changed.

I've tried calling it through `devtools::document`, in a `--vanilla` R sesssion with `roxygen2::roxygenize('taRifx')` from the directory above it, `roxygenize('.')` from the project base directory, tried running as root in case it was a permissions thing, etc.

Here's the RStudio version:

```
==> roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd'))

* checking for changes ... ERROR

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
```

Package code is here:

https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx

How do I fix this?

Comment: Change line 1242 of the Rfunctions.R file to `@examples` instead of `@example`.

Comment: I think you also need to change the `@` in email addresses to `@@` for proper formatting.

Comment: Thank you! If you post as an answer I'll give you the good ole' green checkmark.  Changed `@` everywhere except DESCRIPTION file.  For future reference, how did you find these other than brute-force inspection?  The error message was pretty uninformative.

Comment: I don't know if I'm using a newer version of roxygen2 or if something else is different but after the `error in file...` line it gave some more errors which were from the examples.  Then I noticed that it was example instead of examples, changed that and that fixed that problem.  After roxygenizing it gave an error or warning about the email address.

Comment: Mine just stopped.  Strange.  Thanks for the help.  Package submitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to change line 1242 of the Rfunctions.R file to `@examples` instead of `@example`.  For proper formatting you'll also need to change the `@` in email addresses to `@@`.

Comment: Note that `@@` is `roxygen`'s way of escaping the `@` sign.  Also necessary when using `@` with S4 objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931619/puzzling-unexpected-end-of-input-while-building-package-with-roxygen2?noredirect=1#comment36858657_23931619