# Puzzling "unexpected END_OF_INPUT" while building package with roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm trying to release [this package](https://github.com/gsk3/taRifx.geo), but it keeps failing on build.

I get variations on this in both `build` and `check`:

```
Warning: /tmp/RtmpUUrH6N/Rbuild51f35b160bfe/taRifx.geo/man/interpolateAndApplyWithinSpatial.Rd:66: unexpected END_OF_INPUT '
```

I have traced the problem to a single line in the `@examples` for `interpolateAndApplyWithinSpatial()`:

```
#' \dontrun{
#' require(fields)
#' require(rgdal)
#' distanceMatrix <- function( points1, points2, dist.fn=rdist.earth ) {
#'  cat( "Generating distance matrix for ",length(points1)," by ", length(points2), " matrix.\n" )
#'  if(!is.na(proj4string(points1)))  points1 <- spTransform( points1, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") )
#'  if(!is.na(proj4string(points2)))  points2 <- spTransform( points2, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") )
#'  ##PROBLEMATIC LINE HERE##
#' }
#' } # end of dontrun
```

The `##PROBLEMATIC LINE HERE##` was originally `dist.fn( points1@coords, points2@coords )`, which causes the error message on package build.

If I comment out `dist.fn( points1@coords, points2@coords )`, it still returns an error message.  If I copy and paste the code into the console, it runs.  I've tried re-typing it by hand so I'm sure there's no funny character in there, and it still fails.

The `.Rd` file that gets generated seems to omit everything after the `@`, which leaves it a few `}` short :

```
\examples{
# Not run because too time-consuming
\dontrun{
require(fields)
require(rgdal)
distanceMatrix <- function( points1, points2, dist.fn=rdist.earth ) {
 cat( "Generating distance matrix for ",length(points1)," by ", length(points2), " matrix.\\n" )
 if(!is.na(proj4string(points1)))  points1 <- spTransform( points1, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") )
 if(!is.na(proj4string(points2)))  points2 <- spTransform( points2, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") )
 dist.fn( points1
}
```

My best guess as to what's going on is that `roxygen2` is interpreting `@coords` as a `roxygen2` directive.  Is that right?  And if so how do I fix it?  Short-term fix is to write an accessor function for the `coords` slot and use that, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but if you are using the latest version (`roxygen2_4.0.1.99`) and `roxygenize()` try throwing away the `man` folder and using `document()` from `devtools`, which calls `roxygen2` as it works, instead.  I can't quite say why, but this workflow assures a clean set of `Rd` files and seems to work better/differently than straight `roxygenize()`.  It fixed some problems I was having (that were different from yours, but nevertheless).

Comment: Maybe you should use `coordinates(points1)` instead of trying to access a class member with an @-sign!

Comment: @Spacedman gave the (most likely correct) answer, but it reminded me: `@` is a reserved symbol, so in Roxygen you should "escape" it.  Try `@@` in the roxygen lines.

Comment: @Spacedman That's actually what I changed it to :-).  Old code....  @Andrie Thanks for that.  `@@` was the solution to another `roxygen` problem and now it all makes sense.  Can you post as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbol `@` has special meaning in Roxygen.  So if you need to use `@` in your Roxygen example code (or in any Roxygen field, for that matter) you need to replace it with `@@`.

Thus, the Roxygen segment:

```
#' @examples
#' dist.fn( points1@@coords, points2@@coords )
```

Will translate to the following code in your R man pages:

```
dist.fn( points1@coords, points2@coords )
```

---

Note that in this case you can replace `points1@coords` with `coordinates(points1)`, as observed in the comments.  However, this may not always be possible, depending whether a method exists to index the slot in your S4-class object.

Comment: Thanks @Andrie.  I think it's `sp::coordinates()` though, not `coords()`.